# Unable to find Master Branch option in IntelliJ Community version

Tags: intellij-idea, branch

I have installed the community version of IntelliJ idea and I have cloned the repository.
I can also check the GIT STATUS and GIT PULL commands,
but I cant find an option to swtich from MASTER to a FEATURE branch.
as shown in screenshot, there is no option to display or switch a Branch.

I have tried View - Appearance - Status bar widget option, there is no Branching option available :(

please assist how to fix this issue

[image]

Comment: Is there such a branch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double shift, or click on magnifying glass and type "show git branch"

Also, why don't you use the new UI?

[image]